# Java Servlet Filter not passing POST request + ZOPE

Tags: java, servlets, proxy, servlet-filters, zope

I am using Jetty Transparent Proxy Servlet for integration with ZOPE ( python ). This allows me to apply various java filters without without messing up with ZOPE and its extensions. We are using it mostly for authentication and assigning privileges.

It is working perfectly for regular web pages served by ZOPE ( assuming GET requests ) but its not working when dealing with POST forms hosted on ZOPE.

I discovered that request is properly passed thru the filter chain ( there are few more filters on the way ) something goes wrong at the end. I can observe request reaching ZOPE ( using request logs ) but response never comes back. I have limited ability to investigate anything on ZOPE - only watching its request log.

Its not fault of proxy because when all filters are *switched off* everything works fine.

Can I do something with request/response object? 
Am I missing something in my filters?
Where can I dig more?

Here is stripped down example of the filter I use.

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter{
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

       String secret = request.getParameter("cessotk");
       if ( secret != null && secret.equals (SECRET_TOKEN ) ){
           log ("Discovered secret user");

           session.setAttribute(AUTH_PARAM, true);
           AuthUser secretUser = new AuthUser();
           secretUser.setUsername("SECRET_SYSTEM_USER");

           session.setAttribute(AUTH_USER_KEY, secretUser );
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried to move `chain.doFilter(request, response);` outside `if`? maybe post forms don't send `cessotk` ?

Comment: Yes I tried of course with no luck. As I said here is an example of the filter. I can see in the logs that code is reachable ... see: `log ("Discovered secret user");`